# How to delete a local user in windows 10 and user data

Tags: windows, user-management

How to delete a local user along with the users home directory or data in Windows 10, equivalent to linux command '`sudo userdel -r john`'?

Answer (score 0):

Goto windows start menu and select
[add, edit or remove users option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oPF2.png).
Select local user account which you wanted to delete and click on remove button. In the prompt, select 'Delete account and data'

As shown in screenshot [Select user to be deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKqEK.png),
In case if your user data is still visible on userprofile directory like C:\Users\john, delete the directory manually